# Windows Server 2012 r2 standard with dual NIC + DHCP

Tags: dhcp, ethernet, nic

Currently I have a physical host with Windows Server 2012 r2 standard installed and DHCP role enabled. In addition the physical host has two network interface cards.

I am planing to connect the physical host to two separate physical network. Network A connected to NIC 1 is for a lab no DHCP.
Network B connected to NIC 2 is for DHCP request.

Would it be possible to tell DHCP to only send DHCP to only NIC 2?

I have look on the web and in this forum but no post applies to my setup.

Much appreciate your input.

Answer (score 2):

Sure.

1. Don't bind DHCP to the first NIC.
2. Don't create a DHCP Scope for the first NIC's subnet.

Either of these will do the job, it's not necessary to do both.